# Is there any way to access the Parent object whom called a singleton method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord, singleton-methods

Given the following functional snippet I'm having trouble reducing the database queries:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :account

  def self.do_something
    self.find_each do |user|
      puts "#{self.new.account.name}:#{user.name} did something"
    end
  end
end

class Account < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users
end

a = Account.first
puts 'starting'
a.users.do_something
```

> Account Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "accounts".* FROM "accounts" WHERE
>   "accounts"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
>
> starting
>
> Account Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "accounts".* FROM "accounts" WHERE
>   "accounts"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
>
> Test:User did something
>
> Account Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "accounts".* FROM "accounts" WHERE
>   "accounts"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
>
> Test:User did something
>
> Account Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "accounts".* FROM "accounts" WHERE
>   "accounts"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
>
> Test:User did something
>
> Account Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "accounts".* FROM "accounts" WHERE
>   "accounts"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
>
> Test:User did something

You can see that the Account model is being fetched from the database per user!

I was hoping to use something like `self.account` in the Singleton method to reference the original account, but the relationship obviously doesn't exist  by default which is why I'm currently using `self.new.account`.

Is there anywhere else I can fetch the original Account model saved in `a` from inside `self.do_something`?  I can obviously pass the account in a parameter, but that seems tedious especially if I may add arguments later...

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `find_each` loop, you should be able to use `user.account`.

Outside that loop, I don't believe there's a documented / supported / won't-disappear-without-warning way to find the object. Depending on your Rails version, something like `self.current_scope.proxy_association.owner` might give you the answer you need... but do prefer `user.account` if at all possible: the more you use private APIs, the harder future upgrades can be.

---

Alternatively, consider using [association extensions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-extensions) to define your `do_something` method inside the `has_many` association only -- if it's not suited to be called as `User.do_something` or `User.where(name: "Bob").do_something` (because those don't have an associated `account`), maybe it shouldn't be a top-level method after all.